# Autocomplete source from project settings

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox, application-settings

I want to make an autocomplete string collection and edit it on runtime (add more text to collection) for a search textbox. And list this collection in a listbox. But this collection should be stored in application settings and be restored when i restart the application. How can i do it ? I tried adding a `System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection` type of setting.

I used

```
string newsuggestion = textBox1.Text;
Settings.Default.derslistesi.Add(newsuggestion);
```

"derslistesi" is the name of the `System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection` setting in my application settings. This didn't work. I couldn't edit collection members in runtime.

When i tried to manually add a member to that collection on settings page, i got an error that says "Constructor on type "System.String" not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a setting property of type [`System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) and name it for example `MyProperty`. You can also add some values to it using designer.

To add values to the collection at run-time:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty.Add("Some Value");
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

To set values as auto-complete source for your text box:

```
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty.Cast<string>().ToArray());
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source ;
```