# how to store and retrieve list elements added by winform c# button?

Tags: c#, xml, database, winforms, list

how can I  store and retrieve list elements added by winform c# button ?. I'm trying to add and remove to my block sites list but once I quit app and restart it the elements reset, here are the snippets below

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
```

{

```
     private List<string> BlockList = new List<string>() { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.google.co.uk", "http://www.bing.com" };


private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {



            // BlockList.Add("http://www.google.com");
             //BlockList.Add("http://www.google.co.uk");
            // BlockList.Add("http://www.bing.com"); 

            string[] BlockArray = BlockList.ToArray();  



            for (int i = 0; i < BlockArray.Length; i++)

            {
                if (e.Url.Equals(BlockList[i]))

                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says No!", "NO NO NO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); // Block List Error Message
                }



    private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       BlockList.Add(textBox2.Text);
    }
    private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BlockList.Remove(textBox3.Text);
            }
```

Comment: Using `Settings.settings` file is an option.

Comment: Your Blocklist variable is stored in memory, on the RAM of your computer.  Once your program terminates, all in-memory objects are recycled...

Store it to a file.  There are several ways to do this.  You can add each item to a line of a text file.  Read from the file when you start your program, write to it when your program terminates.

Comment: @RezaAghaei how would I implement that?

Comment: There is a `Settings.settings` file under `Properties` folder of your project. Open it and then add a `User` scoped property of type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. Then add items and save them like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40371672/3110834).

Comment: You need to write out the list box data to something, e.g. text file, database when the application closes, and load it in when you run the application - Look up how to write text files - here is a good vid tutorial to get you started. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cST5TT3OFyg